# @ViewById inside @EBean using android annotations

Tags: android, android-annotations

Can't get @ViewById to work inside an @EBean.

```
@EActivity(R.layout.data_layout)
public class MyActivity extends Activity {
   @Bean
   MyEbean bean;

   @AfterViews
   public void setupView() {
     bean.loadData("Test name");
   }
}

@EBean
public class MyEbean {
   @RootContext
   context;

   @ViewById(R.id.name_field)
   TextView nameField;

  public void loadData(String name) {
    nameField.setText(name); 
  }
}
```

"nameField" in loadData() is null. At the same time if I do this inside loadData()

```
 nameField = (TextView)((Activity) context).findViewById(R.id.name_field);
```

it's all good. So the view is definitely there. Also if I call this method from a retrofit callback (i.e. after a delay) "name" is auto populated. Anything that I'm doing wrong there?

I'm using Android Annotations 3.0.1.

Comment: There is an error in your code too, you're trying to setText of a string  public void loadData(String name) {
    nameField.setText(name); 
  }

Comment: yeah that's nameField, thanks for correction. still will never work with AA :)

Comment: facing same issue...anything change in AA 3.0 onwards........???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`@EBean` annotated classes aren't supposed to do any view-related work as they can be injected in every enhanced classes (ie annotated with `@EService`, `@EBean`, `@EActivity`, ...).

If you're able to do a `findViewById` in the context retrieved via `@RootContext`, it's only because – in this case – the context given to the bean IS the activity. But depending of where the bean is injected, it could also be the ApplicationContext or a Context linked to another acivity/layout.

Comment: Isn't it an AA convention - if it can't find something it just sets it to null? Even within an EActivity there's no guarantee that ViewById will be resolved. By not supporting ViewById within EBean you cut off a lot of potentially useful scenarios for EBean. I, for example, was trying to use EBean to decouple a part of view related logic. A valid scenario.

In any case, shouldn't a pre-compiler complain if anyone's trying to use ViewById within EBean then?

Comment: Coming from the AA tech lead this got to be the "right" answer though, so I'll accept it.

Comment: @Leo look into the EViewGroup annotation for custom views, i'll use them alot for complicated groups of views and then have something like a bind method add data to the view.

Comment: @Brian just got around to explore this area further and must admit found it pretty difficult to use AA outside of straightforward static views/everything in one activity" scenario. Have tried to use it for:
- Decouple view logic out of activity (doesn't work in AA for the reason I described in the original question)
- Dynamically replaced views. You can use .build() on a EViewGroup but it lacks parameters for .inflate, didn't work for me in the same situation where inflate worked fine. ViewStubs - no chance.

Do you have an example of how you use EViewGroups? Maybe I need inspiration :)

Answer (score 2):

@Leo here is an implementation of a custom view and binding data to it. I wanted to make a widget like chips

http://www.google.com/design/spec/components/chips-tokens.html

First define the layout in xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/ivIcon"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/chip_size"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/chip_size"
    android:src="@drawable/default_icon" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvName"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/ivIcon"
    android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
    android:lines="1"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:textColor="@color/secondary_text"
    android:textSize="14sp" />
```

Create a class and annotate it with @eviewgroup
ChipView.java

```
@EViewGroup(R.layout.layout_chip)
public class ChipView extends RelativeLayout{

@App
App app;

public ChipView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);

}

public ChipView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);

}

public ChipView(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

@ViewById(R.id.layoutChipContainer)
View container;

@ViewById(R.id.ivIcon)
ImageView ivIcon;

@ViewById(R.id.tvName)
TextView tvName;

public void bind(User user){

    tvName.setText(user.getUsername());

    app.imageLoader.displayImage(user.getPicture(), ivIcon, app.myResources.iconOptions);
}
```

}

Then in your activity

```
ChipView v = ChipView_.build(context);

v.bind(user);
```

where context is some sort of context and user is an POJO

super easy.

Comment: ok, that's what I was doing as well. Didn't work for me in a RelativeLayout context though - the inflated view wouldn't take the expected position. At the same time `.inflate(view, parent, false)` works like a charm. Guess because of the extra parameters (_build() only does .inflate(view). 
thanks a lot for taking time to answer!

Comment: well if you're inflating a view in code you have to manually set the layout params. if you add a view to a relative layout or framelayout the view will be placed in the top left